# always launch new window from spotlight

Tags: mac, spotlight, alfred

I want to launch new window for all applications every time when i launch an app using spotlight or alfred. Is there any to accomplisht that?

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking the second item can help temporarily. When it's off, opening an app should give it focus on the current space, sometimes new windows open too, afaik.

[image: mission control]

Comment: doesn't works for me